# Change URL in AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, .htaccess

I would like to ask if is possible change the "real URL" for the "hidden URL" in AJAX.
This URL:

```
$.ajax({  
type: "POST",   
url: "http://localhost/process.php",
data: form.serialize(),
dataType : 'json',
success: function(data) {...}
});
```

change to this URL:

```
$.ajax({  
type: "POST",   
url: "http://localhost/hide",
data: form.serialize(),
dataType : 'json',
success: function(data) {...}
});
```

I tried to use .htaccess but this didn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/hide.*$ /process.php [L,QSA]
```

Thx for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^hide$ process.php
```